# How Do I Pass Previous resultPaths to Result.fromObject Pass Task in AWS Step Functions

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I am trying to create an object, from which some are static values, and others are the outcomes of previous tasks. How do I access them?

**Current CDK Code:**

```
this.setupIteration = new Pass(this, "Setup Iteration", {
  result: Result.fromObject({
    "count": "$.skusLength",
    "index": 0,
    "step": 1
  }),
  resultPath: "$.iterator",
});
```

**Error:** I am just getting the string `"$.skusLength"` instead of the actual value that is available above. I have also tried `JsonPath.numberAt` and `JsonPath.stringAt`, with no success.

CDK Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-stepfunctions.Result.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `result` to `parameters`:

```
this.setupIteration = new Pass(this, "Setup Iteration", {
  parameters: {
    "count": JsonPath.numberAt("$.skusLength"),
    "index": 0,
    "step": 1
  },
  resultPath: "$.iterator",
});
```